# Is it possible to select one page only with CSS

Tags: html, css

is it possible to do "only"- or "other"-questions with CSS? Cause I want to change some parameters of a html-element, the parameters shall be the same at every page except one and I can't change the html-code cause I dont have the html-code. I only know that the html-element has the classname "slider" and the slider-element shall only apear at the index-page but currently it's on every page.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Does your index page body happen to have a class? If so you could hide the slider except where .bodyclass .slider?

Comment: your code and [jsfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/) help us to understand your question better

Comment: Show me your html plz

Comment: As others have asked, does the index page have a classname appended to the html / body element? If not, is your site running on PHP as we can write a small script to check which page it currently is and go from from there?

Comment: If you cant change `HTML` and there is no specific Attribute for index page i think you need JS.

Comment: @Aravona  To give the body a specific class is a very nice idea unfortunately I can't change the `HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of css selectors you can use such as: `:first-child`, `:last-child`, `:nth-child()`, and of course `>`, `+` and some more... depending on what it is exactly you're trying to achieve...
You can read more about useful css selectors here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048